# extracting distance between two points from google directions

Tags: google-maps, distance

We have dynamic pages, and user has fixed postocode.

As they go from page to page visiting members profiles, that member has a different postcode perhaps.. probably lol

So if I have the data suburb and postcode of both users, is there a way I can extract the driving directions distance from google maps driving directions ...

Or is there a better way , I recall someone ages ago on here mentioning closeto or nearby etc.

We have absolute full Australian postcode db with lat and lng and suburb name .. just wondering how we could use it to get this extra data.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [blogpost](http://briancray.com/2009/06/23/calculate-driving-distance-google-maps-api/) which explains how this can be done. Tried using it and the results seem accurate enough.

Comment: Word of warning.  Article uses Google Maps API v2, which has been deprecated since 2010.   Suggest try using API v3 to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

In Maps API V3, there's the [Distance Matrix](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/distancematrix.html) which solves this problem exactly.